# Nativescript TabView using to much space when adding title text

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Is it possible to remove some of the padding inside a tabview item?

[image: Tab View]

The TabView has a lot of empty unused space. If I could remove this then my tabs wouldn't get cutoff. This would greatly improve my app since now you have to swipe a bit to the right to see the full title of the last menu item.

The tabview is created in NS-Vue but I don't think that will matter since this is a native issue.

Comment: No, you can not adjust the stylings of default tab view.

Comment: I would suggest you to create your own `GridLayout` to support this

Comment: @Narendra Is it possible to hide the tab buttons? So I can still use the tabview functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using negative margins to remove padding from TabView items. That was the only solution I found to do this. This approach is needed only for Android, for iOS it works fine.

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/page/page';
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TabView } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/tab-view';
import * as platform from 'tns-core-modules/platform';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './tabs.component.html'
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

  tabView: TabView;

  constructor(
    private page: Page,
    private router: RouterExtensions,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tabView = this.page.getViewById('tab');

    this.router.navigate([
      {
        outlets: {
          homeTab: ['home'],
          organizadorTab: ['organizador'],
          favoritosTab: ['favoritos'],
          categoriasTab: ['categorias'],
          perfilTab: ['perfil']
        }
      }
    ], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  @HostListener('loaded')
  onLoaded() {
    if (platform.isAndroid) {
      this.tabView.android.tabLayout.setTabTextFontSize(10);

      const viewGroup = this.tabView.android.tabLayout.getChildAt(0);

      for (let i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        const view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        const layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = 1;

        layoutParams.leftMargin = -20;
        layoutParams.rightMargin = -20;
        layoutParams.topMargin = -20;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -20;

        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
      }

      this.tabView.requestLayout();
    }
  }
}
```